# Local script and css file issue in react-helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I am facing problem with script and css file load in react-helmet.

```
<Helmet>
  <title>Script Testing</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" async="true" src="./script.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./App.css" />
</Helmet>
```

Getting this msg "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." when running script and css file under react-helmet.

How should i run the script and css file before header tag. Please advice.

Which package should I use if react-helmet is not suitable.

[Here is the attached code](https://codesandbox.io/s/script-testing-gkwk1v?file=/src/App.js:102-311)

request you to please help me in this

My requirement is - I need to run script and css file only in some components.

1. The text should appear in red color and in the center
2. Script console should run